# unable to track down AWS TimedStorage-ByteHrs Billing Cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

All the servers (and its volumes) I'm having on AWS EC2 are tagged (customer, app, staging/prod, ...)

When I check the billing, I have a monthly EU-TimedStorage-ByteHrs cost.
This cost only appears for servers with 1 specific tag Customers.
When I track further down, for example checking all the servers for that specific customer, this EU-TimedStorage-ByteHrs cost never appears. Only when I have a look on the group of all servers for that customer.

Any help how I exactly know where this cost EU-TimedStorage-ByteHrs is coming from?

Comment: Seems like S3 in Ireland. Start there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost was an S3 bucket that had a same customer-tag value.
When bucket deleted, EU-TimedStorage-ByteHrs cost is gone.

Comment: Yup :)  hope my comment helped you